# How to only keep lower and uppercase letters and numbers in a string in rust?

Tags: rust

I'm working on a project where I need to scan a file and look for a specific word but I have run into a problem that I'm pretty stuck on. Lets say I'm looking for the word **codeword** in a file and currently my program would succeed in this case

`You'll never find the super secret codeword`

And would fail in this case

`You'll never find the super secret (codeword)`

Here's my code

```rs
for word in file.split_whitespace() {
   vec.push(word.to_string())
}

for i in 0..vec.len() {
    match vec[i].to_lowercase().as_str() {
        "password" => {
            println!("password was found");
            process::exit(0)
         }, 
        "codeword" => {
            println!("codeword was found");
            process::exit(0)
         },
        _ => {
            continue;
        }    
    } 
}
```

How would you filter out all characters except lower and upper case letters and numbers? The spaces must stay because that's how I'm iterating over the words in the file.

After checking the documentation for a string method to do this I found the replace method https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.replace unfortunately this won't work in my case because this text file could supposedly contain any character and there are tens of thousands of possible characters out there

Comment: Why not use [`String::contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.contains)?

Comment: That's a good solution for this specific example but do you know any way to trim a string so only the lower and uppercase letters and numbers remain? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Note that using `to_lowercase()` for comparison is wrong for Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this pretty trivially with the [`regex`](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/index.html) crate.  The `\b` pattern matches on a "Unicode word boundary" which basically means the gap between a word and a non-word.

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use regex::Regex;

fn test(haystack: &str) -> bool {
    lazy_static! {
        static ref RE_CODEWORD: Regex = Regex::new(r"\bcodeword\b").unwrap();
    }
    
    RE_CODEWORD.is_match(haystack)
}

fn main() {
    assert!(test("You'll never find the super secret codeword"));
    assert!(test("You'll never find the super secret (codeword)"));
    assert!(!test("You'll never find the super secret thecodeword"));
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=536c3c92c426e0d58c622ad5d200deef))

---

If your actual goal is to obtain an iterator of words from an input string, this is a bit complicated because it depends largely on what you mean by "word."  If you only want alphanumeric sequences, that's pretty straightforward:

```
fn words(s: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item=&str> {
    s.split(|c: char| !c.is_alphanumeric())
        .filter(|s| !s.is_empty())
}
```

But this won't match the `'` character, so your first example produces this sequence -- note the first word gets split into two words:

```
[
    "You",
    "ll",
    "never",
    "find",
    "the",
    "super",
    "secret",
    "codeword",
]
```

If you want to include punctuation, you have to decide *which* punctuation characters you want to include.

Comment: Thank you so much! I made my own is_alphanumeric function and included spaces thank you